# VAR with categorical variables

Tags: time-series, forecasting, categorical-data, vector-autoregression

I'm currently trying to fit a vector autoregression model to my data set with 4 numerical variables and 1 categorical variable.
To the best of my knowledge, the way to do this is by one-hot encoding the categorical variable, which I have achieved by pandas.get.dummies in python.

However, as I'm fitting the model and trying to project future values for the numerical values, my result becomes weird.

The model can be fitted, however, it does not seem like it can distinguish the one hot encoded variables, and actually project them to be a number else than 0 and 1 (as seen in the screenshot).
[image]

Can anybody help here?
I have attached a screenshot of the data (would be happy to share it as well), and my code can be seen down below: 
`model = VAR(data)

model_fitted = model.fit(12)
#Forecast
lag_order = model_fitted.k_ar
print(lag_order)

Forecast_input = data.values[-lag_order:]

predictions = model_fitted.forecast(y=Forecast_input, steps = 6)`
[image]

Comment: Hi @Sebastian. Just a comment/question from me. Did you ensure that these variables are included in the VAR as `exogenous' variables? Previously when I've used VARs, deterministic elements (trends/dummies/whatever), are treated exogenously.

Comment: Hi @EB3112 thanks for the response! No I'm actually not sure I've done that. So the numerical values should be treated as endogenous variables and the dummies should be treated as exogenous?

Comment: Hi @Sebastian. Dummies should be exogenous, yeah. Unfortunately, I don't use Python, so I can't help you with the code/implementation. But you should endeavour to ensure they're exogenous.